# Acumatica Web API: Reading SO303000.InvoiceSummary.Type Field only returns "Invoice"

Tags: acumatica

Using SOAP Service API, I'm trying to read the Field SO303000.InvoiceSummary.Type to determine if an invoice is of type Invoice, Debit Memo, Credit Memo, Cash Return or Cash Sale. I've made multiple Invoices of each type and then called a basic read for all ReferenceNbrs and their Types using a similar version of the code below. I am able to retrieve all of the Invoices (of all types), however the Type Field for each invoice is always populated as "Invoice" which is different from the SO303000 Screen. Am I reading the wrong Field or is it something else? Thanks!

```
public void GetAllInvoiceTypes()
{
    SO303000Content SO303000 = context.SO303000GetSchema();
    context.SO303000Clear();

    var fields = SO303000.InvoiceSummary;

    List<Command> commands = new List<Command>();
    commands.Add(SO303000.InvoiceSummary.ServiceCommands.EveryReferenceNbr);
    commands.Add(SO303000.InvoiceSummary.ReferenceNbr);
    commands.Add(SO303000.InvoiceSummary.Type);

    String[][] SO303000content = context.SO303000Export(commands.ToArray(), new Filter[] { }, 0, true, true);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This screen has two key fields: type and number. Since you're only specifying `EveryReferenceNbr` in the service commands, and not setting a specific type in the commands, system will only return you the default type, which is Invoice. If you want to get every number of every type, you also have to add `SO303000.InvoiceSummary.ServiceCommands.EveryType` as your first command, before `SO303000.InvoiceSummary.ServiceCommands.EveryReferenceNbr`